# Uniform Border radius and Padding

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items that are displayed with a uniform border-radius. However based on the content size the shape varies from circle to rounded rectangle. How can I get all the items to display with rounded rectangle format irrespective of the content size? Here is a sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tyby62p7/

```
.spanc{
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: have a `min-width:100px` and `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Yes adding a min-width resolved the issue! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want something like this:

```
border-top-right-radius: 25% 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25% 50%;
border-top-left-radius: 25% 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 25% 50%;
```

You can find the example code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4gxjzz0u/) and funy things [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/).

**UPDATE**

Other thing you can do is fix a min-width to your labels.

**Html**

```
<div class="spanc">H</div>
<div class="spanc">Howdy</div>
<div class="spanc">Uh</div>
<div class="spanc">Wow</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.spanc{
    border:1px solid;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25% 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25% 50%;
    border-top-left-radius: 25% 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25% 50%;
    min-width: 80px; /*force to have a minimum width*/
    display: inline-block; /*to keep in the same line*/
    text-align: center
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4fkba5jx/1/).

Comment: Same issue here.. Have a look @ http://jsfiddle.net/4gxjzz0u/1/ teh first span looks like a rounded square..

Comment: So set it to a reasonable number: `border-radius: 10%`

Comment: @prem89 if we can update the 25% dynamically with the `.spanc` width would be great. However I don't know how to do that. I only can advice you to change the 25% to a more reasonable value, like 35% (http://jsfiddle.net/7xqhha4h/) or set a min-width to the `.spanc` (http://jsfiddle.net/4fkba5jx/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using circle? I think it looks better. I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tyby62p7/1/)

**HTML**

```html
<br><div class="spanc"><span class='custom_span'>Hi</span></div>
    <div class="spanc"><span class='custom_span'>Howdy</span></div>
    <div class="spanc"><span class='custom_span'>Uh</span></div>
    <div class="spanc"><span class='custom_span'>Wow</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.spanc{
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;    
}
.custom_span{
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    text-align:center;
}
```